# Swift - Parsing JSON and retrieve data

Tags: json, swift, google-places-api

I am working with Swift on Xcode and I try to parse a JSON file to retrieve some data about nearby stores.
My source code is the following:

```
import GooglePlaces

import SwiftyJSON

class Place {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(diction:[String : Any])
    {
        let json = JSON(diction)
        name = json["name"].stringValue //as! String

        let lat = json["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        let long = json["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, SceneLocationViewDelegate {


var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
        urlString += "&location=51.507514,-0.073603"
        urlString += "&radius=1500" //meters
        urlString += "&name=Specsavers"
        urlString += "&key=**************************" 

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        var places = [Place]()

        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            print("HEREurlSession")
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(json) // json results are printed fine here
                    if let results = json["results"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                        for place in results {
                            places.append(Place(diction: place))
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        print("return")
                    }

                }
                catch{

                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        let size = places.count
        print("HERE: ", size)

}
```

The build is successful but the output is `size = 0` which means that I do not retrieve the data and the variable `places` is empty. 
I do not know if it is exactly relevant but I get the following warning: `Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]' always fails` for the line `if let results = json["results"] as? [[String : Any]]` in my source code.

Why I do not parse the JSON file correctly and I do not retrieve the data the I want to?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you cast `URLRequest` to `URLRequest`? That makes no sense. By the way an `URLRequest` is not needed at all for a `GET` request. And why do you assign `mutableContainers` to an immutable constant? That makes no sense, too

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am catching this source code again now after some weeks and I do not remember from where but I am sure one good tutorial or  a good answer here in SO was suggesting to do this. In this sense, I do not think that this is the problem but if you insist on this then let me know.

Comment: Of course it's not the problem, that's why I wrote *unrelated*. It would be helpful to post the relevant part of the JSON response. The warning reveals that the value of `results` is not `[[String : Any]]`. And `places.count == 0` at at the end of the code is correct because `dataTask` works asynchronously.

Comment: I would recommend using Alamofire for your network requests, it will simplify your life. And also the new Codable Protocol instead of SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` is asynchronous. This means, it runs in the background. You are executing

```
let size = places.count
print("HERE: ", size)
```

while the `dataTask` is still working.

Instead, you should use your result in the completion handler:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        print("HEREurlSession")
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                                    print(json)
                if let results = json["results"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for place in results {
                        places.append(Place(diction: place))
                    }

                }
                else {
                    print("return")
                }

            }
            catch{

            }
        }

        // Use your result here
        let size = places.count
        useResultSize(size)

    }
    task.resume()

    func useResultSize(_ size: Int) {
        // Use your result here
        print("HERE: ", size)
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems, that you are missing what asynchronous execution actually means. Let me try to explain.

Lets mark the execution order in the code:

[image]

First, the red parts of your code are executed. Program execution starts at the top, then moves to the bottom red box and only after that (once the network request is finished) the green part is executed.

That means, that you can only use the result of the network request in the green part of the code. Outside of the green part, the result is not guaranteed to be available.

If you follow my initial advice, than everything should work. Please see the successful execution in my playground:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure if this exactly the problem because I run this in the past like this and it worked fine. Also, if I do what you are suggesting then if I use after this source code a for loop like `for index in 0...size` then I get the following error: `Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and '(UIContentContainer, CGSize) -> CGSize'`.  What am I missing?

Comment: It is **really hard to believe** that this has ever worked. As I said the `URLSession` is asynchronous, so it takes some time to finish and **runs in the background**.

Comment: Your new issue was because `size` was no longer available at the place you used it at, previously. I updated my code to show you an example on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you again for your response but my output is still `size = 0` and this was the principal question of my post. Also, the source code that I posted to my original post is working fine in this sense as I get output `size=0` despite your remarks. Moreover, the API key is working fine because if I paste and search the respective url on Internet then I get the json results on the browser. So what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Please try to read and understand my comments. It is not working because of the reasons that I explained to you. Your original code was never working in the sense that the code will never use the result from the API and will never print anything else than `HERE: 0`. Why? Because the method is asynchronous, as I explained.

Comment: Actually I can even print the json results on the console from the line `print(json)`. I feel that the problem is more related to the warning `Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type '[[String : Any]]'` concerning the line `if let results = json["results"] as? [[String : Any]]` in my source code

Comment: Add added more details to my answer. Your feelings regarding the problem are not correct. The warning is of course valid, but it is not the reason why you always get a size of 0.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will have a look at it now because I was working at something else before.